# Installing AI::MXNet on Perl 5.24

Tags: perl, mxnet

I am unable to install AI::MXNet module on Perl version > 5.24 using Windows 10 and ubuntu 16. I have tried using ppm install AI::MXNet , cpanm install AI::MXNet and cpan install AI::MXNet. I have attached the error message that is being returned. Has anyone has had any success in installing this module.
[image: I have attached error message that is being returned]

Comment: Please, copy the text rather than posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the specific error message: `error: mxnet_wrap.o: No such file or directory`

You need to compile/install MXNet before installing the perl module. See the documentation for details on [building the shared library](https://mxnet.apache.org/get_started/ubuntu_setup.html#build-the-shared-library) and [installing the perl module](https://mxnet.apache.org/get_started/ubuntu_setup.html#install-the-mxnet-package-for-perl).